# Select records with date range filter and history less than date selected

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have to show the current balance of a customer within a selected date range and also add the previous balance if there is any lesser than the date range.

How can this be achieved within a single query? Right now I am doing it with a left join. The current use case is to filter it from Apache Superset where the user will only select the data range and the report will show the current balance and the previous balance records with a date less than the date filter.

Both dataset are from the same entity and joining on customer id. The idea is to show all previous balances the customer has to pay, along with the selected date range. For example, if we select a date between 2023-01-01 to 2023-01-01, then the query will show the customer balance within the selected date range along with the previous balance which have a date before 2023-01-01.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM balance
    WHERE DATE >= '2022-01-01'
        AND DATE <= '2022-01-10'
    ) A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM balance
    WHERE DATE < '2022-01-01'
    ) B ON A.customerID = B.customerID )
```

Comment: What do you expect from LEFT JOIN? It should always return NULL, since the join condition will be never true.

Comment: No it should not always return null, above query is working perfectly. If datasetA has records and datasetB doesnt that means customer doesnt have previous balance we shall coalesce it with zero otherwise previous balance will be add up with datasetA. Look at the joining key please

Comment: @GeorgRichter You're wrong I think join works perfectly. I think you misunderstood about `cid` and you thought it's `id`

Comment: @Alijvhr you got it right

Comment: @OwaisAjaz Actually I wrote an answer for your question but it was closed!

Comment: @OwaisAjaz In fact you are doing it with 3 queries! One for Current, One for previous and One for combine their results! you can do it using one query with a simple join!

```SQL
SELECT *
FROM balance A
    LEFT JOIN balance B ON A.cid = B.cid
    WHERE A.DATE BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-10'
        AND B.DATE < '2022-01-01'
```

Comment: @OwaisAjaz They wont open the question so I wrote my answer here for you!

Answer (score 0):

In fact you are doing it with 3 queries! One for Current, One for previous and One for combine their results! you can do it using one query with a simple join!

```
SELECT *
FROM balance A
    LEFT JOIN balance B ON A.cid = B.cid
    WHERE A.DATE BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-10'
        AND B.DATE < '2022-01-01'
```